# Можно ли читать из середины стека?

Tags: память, стек, процесс

Можно ли прочитать что-то из середины стека, не "выкидывая" элементы из него, пока не дойдем до середины?

**UPD.**
видимо, я неправильно выразился. в общем, хочу понять, как происходит работа со стеком в процессе. у нас есть программа (написана на си), которая запущена. и, предположим, там несколько переменных. они же создаются в стеке. верно?

Comment: Можно, допустим mov eax,[esp+10]

Comment: Зависит от реализации стека

Comment: Вот вам для стека процесса IBM х86 процессора mov eax,[esp+10]

Comment: Уточните что вы понимаете под словом стек. Какую среду используете, какую библиотеку или процессор.

Comment: @nick_n_a конкретно организация динамической памяти. проц 86.

Comment: Всёравно непонятно. это ассемблер паскаль или с++. Используется malloc для памяти, или используется esp указатель на стек. Или это вообще с# или java. Нет никакой конкретики. И вопрос не отражает проблемы, собственно зачем прочитать, и какими средствами. Приведите фрагмент кода как забрасываете в стек хотя бы.

Comment: Ну локальные переменные-то создаются в стеке (то есть _обычно_ создаются в стеке, гарантии нет, могут быть и в регистрах и в хипе, и вообще элиминированы оптимизатором). Но то, где именно, знать заранее невозможно, вы можете лишь делать предположения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно можно. Стек вызовов - это непрерывный массив данных, в котором лежат локальные переменные и, возможно, некоторая другая информация. Локальная переменная в программе обычно представлена смещением относительно вершины стека (есть ещё, как минимум, вариант с регистром). Таким образом обращение к данным, находящимся внутри стека производится постоянно. Ну и ещё, это даёт возможность вызываемым функциям попортить вершину, после чего ничего хорошего не получится. Но это к вопросу вроде не относится.

Comment: а обращение к переменной происходит по, заранее известному, адресу или по обращению к стеку как к стеку?

Comment: @somepeople, в большинстве случае - по смещению от вершины стека. Функция не знает, где её вызовут, значит не может знать точный адрес.

Comment: @somepeople, Обычно, при вызове функции создаётся так называемый [Stack Frame](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80), после этого в регистре (обычно - ebp) находится адрес начала этого кадра. И все переменные в стеке адресуются по фиксированному, в пределах данной функции, смещению [ebp+x].

Comment: сначала переменные создаются в стеке, потом к ним обращаются (изменяют, читают) по смещению относительно конца стека. вопрос решен

Answer (score 1):

Для с++  x86 32-bit ответ

```
CONTEXT ctx;
ctx.Flags = CONTEXT_CONTROL;
if (GetThreadContext(GetCurrentThread(),&ctx)) {
   int * stack = (int*) ctx.Esp;
   // получили массив стека, в котором можно увидеть значения локальных переменных
  // тут можно смотреть стек
   printf("%x", stack[0]);
   }
```

Для некоторых версий с++ можно получить указатель проще

```
int * stack = (int*)_ESP; // borland c++

int * stack; // для тех версий что поддерживают asm, этот вариант так же не все поддерживают
asm { mov eax; esp; mov dword ptr stack, eax; }
```

Многие среды поддерживают dump memory и cpu окно - там визуально можно изучить стек.

И на последок, варварский способ. Стек то есть. Можно взять его и получить примерный адрес стека - взяв адрес локальной переменной (он не равен esp, но уже можно анализировать стек):

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int * stack = (int*)&a;
```

И посмотреть stack[0]; stack[1] и stack[-1];

По организации стека понравилось:
https://rsdn.ru/article/cpp/ObjectsAndPointers.xml c картинками.

Comment: так. стоп. а теперь другой вопрос: действительно переменные создаются и хранятся в стеке?

Comment: Локальные да (в том числе параметры функции/процедуры), глобальные нет. Полученные с помощью new или alloc тоже нет.

Comment: вот смотрите, когда создаем переменную локальную типа инт, потом еще одну. они подряд создаются и стек растет, правильно?

Comment: Да, правильно. И даже больше, взяв адрес одной, и прибавив его - можно записать значение в соседнюю. Например: int a=0; int b[1]; int c=0;  b[1]=1; /*Запись в соседнюю, теперь либо а либо с (cкорее а) равно 1*/. Только нужно переменные задействовать, т.к. компилятор может выбрасывать незадействованые локалыные переменные. Хотя бы вывести все три на экран.

Comment: но все же все это дело хранится в стеке. и как тогда осуществляется доступ к переменным, если нельзя читать не из последней созданной ячейки? или там все по адресам расписано, что чему соответствует?

Comment: Откуда вы взяли что нельзя читать не из последней созданной ячейки? Можно читать из любой, просто ESP указывает на последнюю. Но никто не мешает читать со смещением ([esp + 12], например).

Comment: это уже другой вопрос. В x86 используется либо esp+n либо ebp+n, вычисляется "позиция" стека, а доступ к переменныи идет относительно текуцей позиции. Смещение нахождения стековой переменной относительно вершины стека в каждый шаг выполнения программы - константа. Можно почитать https://rsdn.ru/article/cpp/ObjectsAndPointers.xml

Comment: А теперь вопрос, что вы называете "серединой" стека? С помощью VirtualQuery - можно узнать границу стека - и найти его начало, но, стек поделен на окна. Размер вашего окна можно посчитать как сумму  sizeof локальных переменных, но это не нужно т.к. ваши локальные переменные вам и так доступны. А структура чужих может быть неизвесна. Для каждой процедуры хранятся свои локальные переменные. Если интересно - берите Memory-Dump и копайтесь. Через стек теоретически можно взламывать программы, но это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: "серединой" я называю какое-то место в стеке, не являющееся его концом. спасибо, почитал статью, уточнил некоторые непонятки)

Answer (score 0):

нет. если, конечно, у тебя нет указателя на него, но указатель только на начало стека есть

Comment: а если есть указатель то да? Так да или нет. Или нужно указать что надо уточнить вопрос?

Comment: при реализации списка ты всегда указываешь на начало. у тебя есть указатель на начало. Этот указатель можно поменять на какой нить другой элемент. но тогда весь смысл теряется

Comment: Ответ больше неактуален в связи с уточнением вопроса.